# Xamarin app always working in background

Tags: .net, xamarin

Once I exit the application, I want the application go in tray. So I do't want to turn off the app even when I click on the exit. I tried to overwrite methods that are executed after I exit the application:

```
 protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
            main.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
            StartActivity(main);

            //base.OnStop();
        }
```

Simply I want that, when a user wants to exit the app go in minimize state, and after that display a notification that the application is still working.

Comment: You should look at Android foreground-based services : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

Comment: No, I figure out I need a service that works in the background. Thanks for the answer anyway.